# SQL Bulk Insert UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, sql-server-2014, bulkinsert, codepages

I have a UTF-8 file with a `¬` field delimiter and `[CR][LF]` row terminator. The SQL Version is Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU7) (KB4032541) - 12.0.5556.0 (X64)

I am using bulk insert to load the txt tile in a table as below:

```
DECLARE @bulk_cmd varchar(1000)

SET @bulk_cmd = 'BULK INSERT [test].pcb_Load
FROM ''T:\pcb_Workspace_2\Outputs\pcb\Load\pcb_MS_TEST_2.txt''
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ''¬'', ROWTERMINATOR = '''+CHAR(10)+''',FIRSTROW=2)'

EXEC (@bulk_cmd)

SELECT * FROM test.pcb_load
```

I tried to use code page 65001, Row terminator \r,\n,\r\n,0x0a but nothing works and I get the following error.

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
> The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
>
> Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

So after removing codepage and using CHAR(10) (i.e. above script) my file does load but leaves a hyphen at the end of every string, and in null columns as well.

Output looks like this

```
Col1    Col2    Col3        Col4
-       0-      pcb1412-    DD-
-       0-      pcb2134-    GFD-
-       0-      pcb324-     DDX-
-       0-      pcb1234-    DDR-
```

The data is correct, however the hyphen is not in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `ROWTERMINATOR` to the hex value `'0x0a'` for LF and CR just to be explicit, though that isn't the source of your real problem. I think you are going to have to convert your file to UTF-16. I know earlier versions of SQL Server didn't support UTF-8 and I don't think 2012 does either but could be wrong.

Comment: I had tried it with hex value but no luck. You are correct though, it seems it would come down to converting the file UTF-16.